# ViewController Layout Help Needed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I'm using XCode to build a UI for a countdown timer/metronome app.  After struggling with layout constraints, I discovered vertical and horizontal stack views, which I thought would make things much easier.

However, the outermost stackview's boundaries appear to be outside the view of the device.  I removed all the layout constraints, but that didn't make any difference.

Here's a partial screenshot of the project in XCode:

[StackView boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKCac.png)

Sorry if this question has been asked before - I looked but haven't found anything.

I'm a professional software developer for the last 30 years or so.  The languages I work with on a daily basis for the last 20 years or so are Java, C++, and Fortran.  So dealing with UI layout in IOS is frustrating, to say the least!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the uppermost stack view's size inspector: [size inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sufEt.png)

Comment: Removing all layout constraints does not help. I think there's something wrong with your constrains. For better help, can you screenshot how you applying the constraints for main StackView?

Comment: I added a screensnap - it pastes as a link - I wonder if there's a way to show an image in the body of a post, but not as a link.  I'm sure there must be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your frustration well because it was mine too when I start, and I decided to give you a hand. Make all UI programmatically like this:

in your Controller class built your objects programmatically:

```
let buttonPlay: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .black
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let buttonPause: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "pause.fill")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .black
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let buttonStop: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    let image = UIImage(systemName: "stop.fill")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.tintColor = .black
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    button.clipsToBounds = true
    return button
}()

let minutesLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.text = "MM"
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    return label
}()

let secondsLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .white
    label.text = "SS"
    label.textColor = .gray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    return label
}()

let separatorLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.text = ":"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    return label
}()

let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    label.text = "Title label"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // this distactive automatic constraints
    return label
}()

let timeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.text = "Tempo:"
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .regular)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let imageViewTime: UIImageView = {
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.tintColor = .white
    imageView.backgroundColor = .purple
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

let slider: UISlider = {
    let s = UISlider()
    s.maximumValue = 0
    s.maximumValue = 100
    s.isContinuous = true
    s.tintColor = .black
    s.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderInAction), for: .valueChanged) // call the function below to show slider value
    s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return s
}()

let sliderLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.text = "2"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let containerSlider: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()
```

In viewDidLoad set your background color and call the function to setup the programmatically constraints:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    setupConstraints()
}
```

now set the constraints with autolayout:

```
fileprivate func setupConstraints() {
    let stackViewTime = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [minutesLabel, separatorLabel, secondsLabel])
    stackViewTime.distribution = .fillProportionally
    stackViewTime.spacing = 4
    stackViewTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackViewTime)
    stackViewTime.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackViewTime.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    stackViewTime.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 148).isActive = true
    stackViewTime.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let stackViewPlayer = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [buttonPlay, buttonPause, buttonStop])
    stackViewPlayer.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackViewPlayer.spacing = 10
    stackViewPlayer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(stackViewPlayer)
    stackViewPlayer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170).isActive = true
    stackViewPlayer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    stackViewPlayer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewTime.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    stackViewPlayer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewTime.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(imageViewTime)
    imageViewTime.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewPlayer.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    imageViewTime.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    imageViewTime.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    imageViewTime.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackViewTime.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(titleLabel)
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewTime.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(timeLabel)
    timeLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    timeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    timeLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    timeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    
    let stackSlider = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [sliderLabel, slider])
    stackSlider.distribution = .fill
    stackSlider.spacing = 10
    stackSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    view.addSubview(containerSlider)
    containerSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: timeLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    containerSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    containerSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    containerSlider.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    
    containerSlider.addSubview(stackSlider)
    stackSlider.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerSlider.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerSlider.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackSlider.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerSlider.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    stackSlider.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerSlider.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
}
```

the last step set the function to show the slider value in your slider label when you move it:

```
@objc fileprivate func sliderInAction() {
    sliderLabel.text = "\(Int(slider.value))"
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Play with this code, an experienced developer like you should take a short time to write the code.

Comment: That's a good idea!  Kinda sad that it's easier to build a UI programmatically LOL... Thank you for the suggestion! :-)

Comment: @TracyHiltbrand please check my answer is the right answer... Have a niceday 